# Should I include my NodeJS/Express server code (hosted on Heroku) with my front-end website code (hosted through Firebase)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a simple question regarding the right practice to utilize a NodeJS/Express server. Currently, I have my NodeJS server hosted on Heroku. Separately, I have my front-end website hosted through Firebase. I communicate back and forth via Socket.io.

My question is: should I migrate my NodeJS code to my front-end code so that it is hosted in the same directory through Firebase? I'm confused about whether to host them in the same directory or if I should continue hosting them as I am...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you are communicating through socket.io it should be safe to leave the code.